# django,edit form with unique field, form.is_valid return false

Tags: django, forms, unique

```
class modelA(..):
    fieldA = ...     unique
    fieldB = ...     unique

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['fieldA','fieldB']]


class formA(modelform):

    class Meta:
        model = modelA
        field = ['fieldA','fieldB']


def viewA(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formA(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():          here return false !!!!!
            ......
```

In **edit** form, when click submit button to update the database, the form.is_valid() return false because the unique_together check , how to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the `instance` argument with the model instance which you want to edit:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def viewA(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(modelA, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formA(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
```